# Merge tab delimited files by key

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have three MapReduce jobs that produce tab delimited files, that operate on the same files. The first value is the key. This is the case for every output of these three MR jobs.

What I want to do now, is use MapReduce to "stitch" these files together by key. What would be the best Mapper output and Reducer input? I tried using ArrayWritable, but because of the shuffle, for some records the ArrayWritable from 1 file is in the third position, instead of the second.

I want this:

```
Key \t Values-from-first-MR-job \t Values-from-second-MR-job \t Values-from-third-MR-job
```

And this should be the same for **all** records. But, as I said, because of the shuffle, sometimes this happens for a few records:

```
Key \t Values-from-third-MR-job \t Values-from-first-MR-job \t Values-from-second-MR-job
```

How should I set up my Mapper and Reducer to fix this?

Comment: Maybe secondary sorting and a manual prefix in the values (one per MR-job) is what you are looking for... have a look (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html)

Comment: @vefthym Thanks for that tip. I will look into it! If I can manage something, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with simple tagging on the emitted value since only three types of files are involved. In map extract the path of the split, identify its position and add a suitable prefix to the value. For clarity, say the outputs are in 3 directories :

1. path1/mr_out_1
2. path2/mr_out_2
3. path3/mr_out_3

Using `TextInputForamt` for all these paths, in `map` you will do :

```
String[] keyVal = value.spilt("\t",2);

Path filePath = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath();
String dirName = filePath.getParent().getName().toString();

Text outValue = new Text();
if(dirName.equals("mr_out_1")){
    outValue.set("1_" + keyVal[1]);
} else if(dirName.equals("mr_out_2")){
    outValue.set("2_" + keyVal[1]);
} else {
    outValue.set("3_" + keyVal[1]);
}

context.write(new Text(keyVal[0]), outVal);
```

If you have all the files in the same directory, use the fileName instead of dirName. Then identify the flag based on the name(a regex match may be suitable)  :

```
String fileName = filePath.getName().toString();
if(fileName.matches("regex")){ ... }
```

In `reduce` just put the incoming values to a List and sort. Rest is simple enough.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(3);
for(Text v : values){
    list.add(v.toString());     
}
Collections.sort(list);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : list){
    builder.append(s.substring(2)+"\t");    
} 

context.write(key, new Text(builder.toString().trim()));
```

I think it will serve the purpose. Keep in mind that the `Collection.sort` strategy will fail if there are more than 9 files (due to alphabetical order). Then you may extract the tag separately, cast it to an `Integer` and use a `TreeMap<tag, actualString>` for sorting.

NB: All the above snippets are using new API. I didn't use an IDE to write those, so few syntax errors may exist. And again I didn't follow proper conventions in writing. Say the outKey of `map` could be a class member, and using `outKey.set(keyVal[0])` could remove a `Text` object creation overhead.

Comment: This was a good suggestion and implementing it was fairly straight forward. Thanks @blackSmith